# 99 toyota avalon

Tags: ignition, no-crank-no-start, avalon

To start,I just replaced my alternator and my battery is full charged. My car has a problem starting. I looked it up and found a suggested bad start relay. I bypassed the start relay with a jumper wire to start my car until I could replace the relay. I finally replaced the relay and so my car worked however, it only worked for four days. As of right now the same problem is occurring agin.i put the key in and try to start but no clicking or anything. I can still start it by bypassing the relay. This relay is new, what's my problem??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Just because it's a new relay doesn't mean it hasn't gone bad, too. You might try another one and see what happens.

Comment: Perhaps troubleshooting the starting circuit with wiring diagrams may help you find the problem. This may be as simple as a broken/damaged wire, severe corrosion on a wire, loose connections, poor main grounds. A wiring diagram is the first thing to have instead of guessing.

Comment: Thanks for replying,  I'll see if I can't find a wire diagram and maybe test that relay as well.